# Best way of styling CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image]

I'm using **css grid** and in this case **i have made a div** that fit in a grid (the **green** box)(at the right the color is green not yellow) and **inside this div i have made another grid** (2 columns) and in one at the **left** there is the **image** and **at the right** there is **another div** (the **red** one) **with a paragraph.**

As you can see i have used and height of 61vh otherwise the image doesn't fit well and than i had to set also an height for the red box otherwise it goes outside of the green box.[image: img3] [image]
I think this is not ther right way of doing it, how can i **do it without** setting an **exact height**?

```
.GreenBox{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: 6/7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 61vh;
    display: grid;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    border: 2px solid greenyellow;
}

.RedBox{
    grid-column: 2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 60.6vh;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.PurpleBox{
    grid-row: 2;
    border: 1px solid blueviolet;
}

.Image{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto ;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}




                 <div className="GreenBox">
                    <img className="Image" src={foto2}/>
                    <div className="RedBox">
                        <p className="Paragraph">ILorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas a tellus eget velit cursus feugiat. Proin quis condimentum velit, a pellentesque erat. Maecenas consectetur eros et nibh condimentum pharetra. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**PS: the problem is that if that if i resize the page there is always a bottom gap, i would like to remove that and fit well the content in the greenbox.**

Comment: `vh` isn't an exact height. Its a percentage of the view window height. There is nothing wrong using it when your design requires it.

Comment: yeah but i'm afraid that on another screen it doesn't fit well

Comment: @Ladvace There is no harm done in resizing the browser, to test it on different screen resolutions. Otherwise you might want to look at another unit.

Comment: can you please provide the html also

Comment: this might help https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejNeLW

Comment: yeah it's usefull but the problem is that i'm using css grid in my page

Comment: Try using display:block; and height:100%; in your .RedBox css.

Comment: The Layout looks so simple and it doesn't require you to have embedded grids, CSS grid came to eliminate the need for wrappers, does [This](https://jsfiddle.net/f3ugzLho/) looks like what you want

Comment: i'm using grid to align elements in the page

Comment: because i have some of them in the page with the paragraph at right instead of left